# delete rows from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have one database named project1. it has more than 200 tables with different names.
each table have some entries.

Now i want to delete those entries from all the table which has timestamp below 2017-12-30 23:59:50(i just want to keep entries in database from 2018 on wards).

how to write sql query for the same?

Comment: Maybe think about restructuring your data

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete multiple tables in a single sql statement when joining them.  And there's no good way to join your tables in such a way as to find just the records you want.  Instead just do one table at a time:

```
delete from table1 where Date <= '2017-12-30 23:59:50';
delete from table2 where Date <= '2017-12-30 23:59:50';
...
```

Wrap it in a transaction if you want it all to take effect at once.

To do this in a single query for up to 60 tables at once, you could do something like:

```
delete t1,t2,t3
from (select Date from table1 union select Date from table2 union select Date from table3) d
left join table1 t1 on t1.Date=d.Date
left join table2 t2 on t2.Date=d.Date
left join table3 t3 on t3.Date=d.Date
where d.Date <= '2017-12-30 23:59:50';
```

but I have no idea how inefficient that is going to be and don't see any reason you'd want to do that instead of just using multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it won't worked for me

Comment: @VimalNayak what query did you do and what error did it give?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax was not correct

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INT,
>   `date` DATE,
>   week_day  varchar(10)
>   
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 (
>   `id` INT,
>   `date` DATE,
>   week_day  varchar(10)
>   
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table3 (
>   `id` INT,
>   `date` DATE,
>   week_day  varchar(10)
>   
> );
> ```

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `date`,week_day)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2017-07-22',NULL),
>   ('2', '2017-07-28',NULL),
>   ('3', '2020-07-30',NULL),
>   ('4', '2020-07-27',NULL),
>   ('5', '2020-07-28',NULL),
>   ('6', '2020-08-15',NULL),
>   ('7', '2017-07-27',NULL),
>   ('  8', '2020-07-29',NULL),
>   ('9', '2020-07-31',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2
>   (`id`, `date`,week_day)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2017-07-22',NULL),
>   ('2', '2017-07-28',NULL),
>   ('3', '2020-07-30',NULL),
>   ('4', '2020-07-27',NULL),
>   ('5', '2020-07-28',NULL),
>   ('6', '2020-08-15',NULL),
>   ('7', '2017-07-27',NULL),
>   ('  8', '2020-07-29',NULL),
>   ('9', '2020-07-31',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table3
>   (`id`, `date`,week_day)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2018-07-22',NULL),
>   ('2', '2018-07-28',NULL),
>   ('3', '2020-07-30',NULL),
>   ('4', '2017-07-27',NULL),
>   ('5', '2017-07-28',NULL),
>   ('6', '2020-08-15',NULL),
>   ('7', '2017-07-27',NULL),
>   ('  8', '2020-07-29',NULL),
>   ('9', '2020-07-31',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> DELETE  t1,t2,t3 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 , table3 t3 
> WHERE t1.`date`  <= '2017-12-30 23:59:50' AND
> t2.`date`  <= '2017-12-30 23:59:50' AND
> t3.`date`  <= '2017-12-30 23:59:50'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | week_day
> -: | :--------- | :-------
>  3 | 2020-07-30 | null    
>  4 | 2020-07-27 | null    
>  5 | 2020-07-28 | null    
>  6 | 2020-08-15 | null    
>  8 | 2020-07-29 | null    
>  9 | 2020-07-31 | null
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | week_day
> -: | :--------- | :-------
>  3 | 2020-07-30 | null    
>  4 | 2020-07-27 | null    
>  5 | 2020-07-28 | null    
>  6 | 2020-08-15 | null    
>  8 | 2020-07-29 | null    
>  9 | 2020-07-31 | null
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table3
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | week_day
> -: | :--------- | :-------
>  1 | 2018-07-22 | null    
>  2 | 2018-07-28 | null    
>  3 | 2020-07-30 | null    
>  6 | 2020-08-15 | null    
>  8 | 2020-07-29 | null    
>  9 | 2020-07-31 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a3fb45667a2a38776dbf44ed8f8d361)*

a stored procedure will be like this, you have to adept the select statement
The dat you can make flexible as well

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `dowhile`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `dowhile`()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE _tablename varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
    
    DEClARE curtable_name 
        CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            TABLE_NAME
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME LIKE 'testr%';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN curtable_name;

        gettable_name: LOOP
                FETCH curtable_name INTO _tablename;
            IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE gettable_name;
            END IF;
            -- build email list
            SET @sql = CONCAT("DELETE  FROM ",_tablename," WHERE `date`  <= '2017-12-30 23:59:50';");
            PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
            EXECUTE stmt1;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
        END LOOP gettable_name;
    CLOSE curtable_name;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If there are no rows for 2017 in any of the tables then nothing is deleted: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fde664e96a63841d8310ea9773bf9e5d

Comment: Your suggestion is appreciated but i have more than 200 tables in the database so is it possible to apply any other logic?

Comment: @VimalNayak I think you are seeing some problem with using multiple queries that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: then you write a stored procedure, with INFORMATION_SCHELA, you can grab all tablenames that fit the descripton and ruh an statement that delets one by ine in loop and please when you write 3 tablesm, then i give an answer for 3 tables,

Comment: i have retrieved all table names by  INFORMATION_SCHELA but not aware how to write stored procedure.

Comment: i have added the stored procedure for that porpose, you have ti chamge the select TABLE:NAME of course